# can't login with Paramiko ssh client

Tags: python, ssh, client, paramiko

local-host --->Aterm server (security server ) -----> target-machine(
I am trying to write a code in Python using Paramiko to first SSH from local-host to the target-machine. From the target-machine, I want to capture some outputs and store them locally either as a variable or as a file (havent got to that point yet). I found an example from stackoverflow where they talk about using nested SSH with paramiko, and I follow it but I get stuck here:
i need just reaching the target-machine

My code:

```
import paramiko
import sys
import subprocess
hostname = '10.10.10.1'
port = 22
username = 'mohamed.hosseny'
password ='Pass#1'
client = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
client.connect(username=username, password=password)
client.close()
```

but i found the below error message :

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mohamed.hosseny/Desktop/Paramiko.py", line 13, in <module>
  client = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 332, in 
  __init__
   'Unable to connect to {}: {}'.format(hostname, reason))
   SSHException: Unable to connect to 10.10.10.1: [Errno 10060] A connection 
   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after 
   a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host 
    has failed to respond
```

Comment: is `10.10.10.1` the *target-machine*? or the *security server*?

Comment: 10.10.10.1 is target-machine

Comment: scenario  : 
Local machine ----> Aterm server (Linux authentication server ) -----> target Router 



******my quotation is *******
how i can by pass the authentication server?
 that i have the right credential to login it .

Comment: how do you manually login with ssh?

Comment: **via SecureCRT application**                                                                                                            with                                                                                                             `'hostname = '10.10.10.1'   `
`port = 22`
`username = 'mohamed.hosseny`
`password ='Pass#1'  `     @pynexj

Answer (score 1):

`paramiko.Transport` is a lower level API. Don't use it unless you have a good reason. Instead, you can use `paramiko.SSHClient`.